# Android data binding stopped working after opening other app

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm using Android data binding in my login Activity, with AndroidViewModel.

in the layout xml:

```
 <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="loginVm"
        type="com.winners.viewmodel.LoginViewModel" />
</data>
```

and I'm creating the binding like the following in the onCreate method of my activity:

```
  mLoginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    mBinding.setLoginVm(mLoginViewModel);
```

I'm binding the data in my layout xml like the following :

```
android:text="@={loginVm.username}"
```

which is observable field :

```
public final ObservableField<String> username = new ObservableField<>();
```

or

```
android:text="@={loginVm.logInMsg}"
```

which is observable field :

```
 public final ObservableField<String> logInMsg = new ObservableField<>();
```

or onclick binding:

```
 android:onClick="@{loginVm::logIn}"
```

everything works fine, until I open other app from my app, suddenly the data binding text stops working, and when I update the text from the code, the layout does not change accordingly. but onClick binding keeps working. only text binding from code is not working after opening another app.

I googled it a lot and did not find an answer for this weird behavior.
Hope someone can help me here to discover what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think your observer is not working properly os check your observer how to store data in data model.

Comment: I developed the databinding according to android databinding tutorial [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability).
and as I mentioned it does work properly, until I open other app from my app.